# IIS with alternate name in SAN Cert prompts for Credentials

Tags: authentication, iis, storage-area-network

I have a server (server01) running IIS with a Web certificate installed. The certificate has the following SANs -

- server01.companyname.com
- server02.companyname.com

The binding on Default Web Site for HTTPS for 443 has no HostName specified (intentionally left blank). The site configured has Windows Authentication enabled.

When accessing the website with server01.companyname.com, all works well.

But when accessing the website with server02.companyname.com, the user is repeatedly prompted for user credentials (logs show 401)

What am I missing?